# Angular binding not firing before blocking call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When a user clicks a button on my form, I want it to disable all controls and then go off to the server to perform the action, so they cannot then change any values until the result comes back. When the result comes back, the form can be re-enabled.

However this is my code

```
$scope.restartNode = function () {
            $scope.isBusy = true;
            $scope.disableControls = true;

            SEApplicationService.restartNode();

            $scope.isBusy = false;
            $scope.disableControls = false;
        }
```

The restartNode is the blocking call to a Web API method, however the controls do not get disabled. If I comment out the final line - setting the controls back to enabled, I can see all the form controls greyed out as expected. What is happening here?

My blocking call is

```
appService.restartNode = function () {
        return $http.post("/SEFlex/SEFlexAdmin/RestartNode", {
            isPrimary: appService.primarySelected
        }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
            appService.refreshData();
        }).error(function (reason, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(reason);
        });
    }
```

Edited: to add the refreshData() function

```
appService.refreshData = function () {
        return $http.post("/SEFlex/SEFlexAdmin/GetNodesStatus")
            .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                if (response) {

                    angular.forEach(response.data, function(value) {
                        if (value.isPrimary) {
                            appService.ServiceStatus.PrimaryStatus = value.status;
                            appService.ServiceStatus.PrimaryPools = value.poolCount;
                            appService.ServiceStatus.PrimaryContainers = value.containerCount;
                            appService.ServiceStatus.PrimaryNodes = value.nodeCount;
                        } else {
                            appService.ServiceStatus.SecondaryStatus = value.status;
                            appService.ServiceStatus.SecondaryPools = value.poolCount;
                            appService.ServiceStatus.SecondaryContainers = value.containerCount;
                            appService.ServiceStatus.SecondaryNodes = value.nodeCount;
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .error(function (reason, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(reason);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the request is asynchronous and you aren't waiting for the response to change your `busy` and `disable` variables.

Wrap them into the promise callback of `restart`

```
 $scope.restartNode = function () {
        $scope.isBusy = true;
        $scope.disableControls = true;

        SEApplicationService.restartNode().then(function(){
            $scope.isBusy = false;
            $scope.disableControls = false;
        }).catch(function(err){
            // any promise rejected in chain will be caught  here
        });            
    }
```

EDIT: to properly create promise chain of `restartNode` and `refreshData` you need to switch out `success` for `then`. This is one reason `success` is being deprecated:

```
appService.refreshData = function () {
    return $http.post("/SEFlex/SEFlexAdmin/GetNodesStatus")
        .then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
             var responseData = response.data;
            if (responseData ) {

                angular.forEach(responseData.data, function(value) {
                    // code left out for brevity
                });
            }
        });
 }
```

Then you can return the `refreshData` promise in the `then` of `SEApplicationService.restartNode()`

```
 appService.restartNode = function () {
    return $http.post("/SEFlex/SEFlexAdmin/RestartNode", {
        isPrimary: appService.primarySelected
    }).then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
        return appService.refreshData();
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will the then() method run before or after the success() part of the asynch call? ie will appService.refreshData() run and fully complete before the then() promise gets called?

Comment: is `appService.refreshData();` asynchronous too? If so does it return `$http`? Can chain the promises if so but need to use `then` instead of `success`

Comment: Just edited the post to show the refreshData() function

Answer (score 0):

u can use callback function for that like this

```
$scope.restartNode = function () {
            $scope.isBusy = true;
            $scope.disableControls = true;

            SEApplicationService.restartNode(function(){

                  $scope.isBusy = false;
                  $scope.disableControls = false;

             });

        }
```

here is the server function

```
appService.restartNode = function (callback) {
        return $http.post("/SEFlex/SEFlexAdmin/RestartNode", {
            isPrimary: appService.primarySelected
        }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
            appService.refreshData();
            callback();
        }).error(function (reason, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(reason);
            callback();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

put a scope.$apply() after $scope.disableControls = false;